# Como controlo ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

quiero manejar las excepciones que tiene hibernate con respecto a la hora de insertar entradas que ya están duplicadas. Tengo en mi base de datos una restricción que es la de clave primaria llamada PK_ANIMAL y tengo el objeto mapeado con hibernate funcionando correctamente. Inserta bien pero es eso, quiero controlar las excepciones. He estado investigando y se ve que por donde quiero ir es con la excepción de ConstraintViolationException (a lo mejor me equivoco).

Entonces lo que quiero es que si entra en el catch porque la entrada está duplicada, pues mostrar por consola (para debuggin) pero cuando transformo la excepción de PERSISTENCE a la de CONSTRAINT no hace ni el System.out.println(...)

---

**La librería de hibernate que uso es la v5.5.7 y la librería que uso
para trabajar con MARIADB es mysql-connector-java-8.0.26**

---

Este es mi método de la clase que gestiona los crud de la base de datos (La clase se llama GestionBD):

```
public boolean insertar(animal an) {
        try {
            
            //  PARA PODER HACER UNA INSERCIÓN SE INICIA LA TRANSACCIÓN
            session.beginTransaction();
            
            //  SE HACE LA INSERCIÓN
            session.save(an);
            
            //  PARA QUE LA TRANSACCIÓN SE TERMINE Y QUEDE REALMENTE EL OBJETO INSERTADO EN LA TABLA
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            
            //  SE CIERRA LA SESIÓN Y CONEXIÓN
            session.close();
            factory.close();

        //  SI SE VIOLA UNA RESTRICCIÓN     
        }catch(PersistenceException e) {
        
            if(e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
                ConstraintViolationException cve = (ConstraintViolationException) e;
                //  COMPROBAR EL CODIGO DE ERROR Y SI ES SQLState: 23000 HACER SYSOU DE QUE ESTÁ DUPLICADA
            }
            
            //  SE CIERRA LA CONEXIÓN
            factory.close();
            
            return false;
        //  EXCEPCIÓN POR DEFECTO
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

Soy bastante nuevo en hibernate y estoy trabajando según me han explicado en clase, así que si tengo algún error me disculpo por adelantado. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

En Java puedes poner múltiples Catch dentro de un try y se ejecutarán de arriba hacia abajo en orden, por lo que para controlar la excepción deberías poner un Catch con ConstraintViolationException y otro con Exception por si ocurre cualquier otra cosa inserperada.

Otra cosa que modifico es el cierre de sesión y de factory ya que se deben hacer siempre en un bloque finally. Esto hará que siempre se ejecute exista una excepción o no, de esta forma evitaremos dejar recursos abiertos en memoria.

```
public boolean insertar(animal an) {
    try {
        
        
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(an);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
  
    }catch(ConstraintViolationException e) {
         //TRATAMIENTO DE ESTA EXCEPCIÓN CONCRETA
         return false;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        // ANTE CUALQUIER OTRA EXCEPCIÓN EJECUTAMOS OTRAS OPERACIONES.
        return false;
    } finally {
        if(session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
        if(factory != null) {
             factory.close();
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```